# Set up an organization domain on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

We use a vendor that are the owners of the billing account. Our projects are linked to that billing account. Now, we want to enable role based support but it seems that we don't have an organization so we cant enable this. We do not use g-suite nor want to. What is the best approach to create an organization in the gcp account? Cloud Identity?

I tried to enable Cloud Identity but my email is registered as "private account" and cant use it when enabling. I registered my email as private account months ago when we were given access to the gcp account.

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Cheers,
Cris

Comment: Do you own a domain name. You will need an email address in that domain to setup  an organization. Then look at Google Identity Server.

Comment: Yes we own the domain. The problem is also that my email in that domain is registered as a private account so I can’t use it to register the cloud identity service.

Comment: I need more details. What account(s) do you have? What problems are you having with IAM? What is the exact message regarding "private account" and where are you getting this message? If you have a GCP account, are you the account Project Owner? Edit your question with these details.

Comment: I am the project owner and organization administrator and I use my email with the domain I try to register. So, this is the email I use when registering Cloud Identity but it says (in Swedish thats why its not exactly) "This email is registered as a personal account".